# How to initialize a multi-dimensional array in PHP presetting the keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, initialization

I have a constant defined as:

```
define('CONFIG_CODES', 'v1,v2,v3');
```

I want to initialize a multi-dimensional array using the config codes defined in my constant as the array keys. I have tried `array_fill_keys()` and a variety of other methods and I cannot get the array to initialize. The reason I want to initialize is to avoid `Undefined index: v2` and `Undefined offset: 0` in my PHP script results.

Here is what I want the initialization to look like:

```
Array
(
    [v1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [v2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [v3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

**My Attempt:**

`$serviceTimes = array_fill_keys( array( CONFIG_CODES ), '' );`

Comment: You could define `'CONFIG_CODES'` to be an array as you structured it below?

Comment: Well, I was preferring to do it programmatically in PHP. I already have explode()'d the constant and I have a `foreach()` going to recognize the individual keys. I just can't figure out how to take each config code and and set it as the array key to initialize @Ice76

Comment: Could you show your attempt to initialize the keys? I could help there @OP

Comment: I amended my OQ @Ice76

Comment: You were almost there, using `array_fill_keys(explode(',', CONFIG_CODES), array(null, null))` ([3v4l](https://3v4l.org/RB4f1)) would do the trick (adjust the `array(...)` part with what you want as each array item's value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty `$initialized` array, then loop through the exploded result of your constant value, using the exploded values as associative keys:

```
define('CONFIG_CODES', 'v1,v2,v3');
$initialized = array();
foreach(explode(',', CONFIG_CODES) as $val){
    $initialized[$val] = array(
        'val1',
        'val2'
    );
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried that and still got the PHP warning on index and on offset, but I'll try it again. Thanks @commanderZiltoid

Comment: The above example outputs correctly on my machine. If you receive an error message, let me know what it is.

Comment: This one worked. I think I neglected the initial `$initialized = array();`. I know that because I did not recall having that during one of my attempts. Thanks so much for helping!!

Answer (score 1):

This could be something like what you are looking for?

```
define( 'CONFIG_ARRAY', 'v1, v2, v3' );
define( 'VALUES', 2 );

function makeArray()
{
    $array = array();
    $versions = explode( ',', CONFIG_ARRAY );
    foreach ( $versions as $version )
    {
        $array[$version] = array();
        for( $i = 0; $i < VALUES; $i++ )
        {
            $array[$version][$i] = '';
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

This would be a generator function, but you can remove the code from the function and use it to make your array.

Comment: Thanks @Ice76. This one might work but I tested and used the other answer. It is more compact (lighter) as well.